# Can i initiate a view controller dynamically using nib file downloaded from web server?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

How to change the view of the view controller using nib file downloaded from web server. is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is dynamic code insertion possible in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416010/is-dynamic-code-insertion-possible-in-iphone)

Comment: Funny: Two conflicting answers, but nobody tried... Maybe it's not so much a question of technical possibilities, but of will-it-make-it-to-the-app-store and I don't think it would...

Answer (score 2):

See the answer in your other question that addresses this same issue. [Is dynamic code insertion possible in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416010/is-dynamic-code-insertion-possible-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only load NIBs from the NSMainBundle. And the NSMainBundle is your .app Directory, which you can't edit on the device. So it won't work.

Comment: // If the bundle parameter is nil, the main bundle is used.
+ (UINib *)nibWithData:(NSData *)data bundle:(NSBundle *)bundleOrNil;

Comment: hoe to specify the path for nib to load form document directory