# Is dynamic code insertion possible in iphone?

Tags: iphone, dynamic

Each time i make small changes, i need to submit the app for approval and need to wait to review process to complete, so till what extent i can exploit dynamic code insertion or at least can i change the view of a view controller using the nib file which i will be downloading to document directory dynamically?

Comment: I'm guessing the whole point of the review process is to make sure nothing dodgy is going on. Circumventing that process would probably be stopped by said process :)

Comment: Maybe if you tested your app a bit more you wouldn't have to keep submitting it.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, the answer is no, and intentionally so. In particular, you cannot run executable code that you download. If you figured out a workaround to allow it technically (and I have at least one or two thoughts in mind on how I'd attack it), it would definitely run counter to Apple's approval process.

On the other hand, a nib file is data, not code. That you can definitely read from disk and instantiate using `[UINib nibWithData:bundle:]`. This is a pretty big hassle, though, and I don't particularly recommend it. But it's relatively straightforward (unless you want to correctly handle low memory situations, in which case it's a bit more of a hassle).

Of course you can always have dynamic code by putting it in a webview and writing it in JavaScript.

In the end, though, the review process is the way it is on purpose, and I recommend developers adapt their development cycle to include it. That generally means having fewer releases with heavier testing because "one quick fix" is expensive.